# Pipe output from one program to another

Tags: powershell, pipe, exe

In powershell, I am trying to pipe the output of from one exe to another. I can do it in the command prompt but can't seem to make it work in powershell. In the command prompt I do this...

```
Program1.exe -param "myParameter" | Program2.exe myOtherParameter
```

Does anyone know how to do this in powershell? I've tried....

```
set-alias Program1 "C:\....Program1.exe"
set-alias Program2 "C:\....Program2.exe"
........
Program1 -param $something | Program2 $somethingElse
Program1 -param $something > Program2 $somethingElse
Program1 -param $something | out-file Program2 $somethingElse
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem.  You may want to [vote on the issue on the Connect site](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/691490/pipe-operator-corrupts-raw-binary-data).  There is a workaround posted here: http://www.powershellcookbook.com/recipe/WCiL/capture-and-redirect-binary-process-output

But that site seems to be temporarily down.